# Django REST browsable API List view after create only displays created instance

Tags: django, list, rest, view, django-rest-framework

Django REST default browsable API behavior after posting a form is to display the list view with ONLY the newly created instance. Makes sense from an API perspective as a response to a create but I would like the browsable interface to display ALL instances in the list after the create.

Can I customise this behavior for the html response somehow?

I think ideally it would display the entire list and put the contents of the newly created instance in the form for possible updating - in case user made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can customize this. You have to overwrite the `create` method. 
A possible solution would be something like this:

```
def create(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # call create of parent class
    super(ModelViewSet, self).create(*args, **kwargs)
    # but return the list view
    return self.list(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thank you - if I override the create I could just redirect to the list after checking the format parameter for api format.